# Restkit - Post object

Tags: ios, http-post, restkit, restkit-0.20

I try to post an object *Foobar* (the class has two attributes: *string foo* and *string bar*) using the method *postObject* of the class RKObjectManager.

Server-side, I have a WCF service that receive the POST method

```
public void PostFoobar(Foobar foobar) { ... }
```

All the connection works. The problem is that the object foobar received is always NULL. It seems ResKit does not POST my object as an encapsulation of the two arguments, but post two string independently.

I mean, when I tryed to implement the following method (server-side) :

```
public void PostFoobar(string foo, string bar) { ... }
```

and the two parameters was not null ! it has worked !
But I would prefer to recover the serialized object obviously...

#### My question is :

How am I suppose to configure my POST request to recover an entire Foobar object on the server side, and not every attributes independently ?

#### My code

Here is my code to send the POST request

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = @"myObjecModel";
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

// Configure the object manager
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.10/rest"]];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];

RKEntityMapping *postMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Foobar" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[postMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"foo" : @"strFoo",  // server side:foo, iOS side: strFoo
 @"bar" : @"strBar"   // server side:bar, iOS side: strBar
 }];
RKRequestDescriptor * requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[postMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Foobar class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

// POST to create
RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore];
Foobar *foobar = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Foobar" inManagedObjectContext:objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
foobar.strFoo = @"foo ipad";
foobar.strBar = @"bar ipad";

@try {
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:foobar path:@"foobar" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"error - %@", exception);
}
```

One more thing :

I have tested my web service with the chrome client "*Simle REST client*" and it works with the data :

```
{ "foo": "foo from chrome", "bar" : "bar from chrome" }
```

### Edit - Frame capture with Wireshark

[image: frame capture with wireshark]

It seems to be good.. I don't understant.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling with `nil`:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:@"foobar" parameters:nil ...
```

So RestKit is given nothing to serialise and no parameters.

If that's a typo, turn on trace logging for mapping and look at what it's doing. Also, get Charles or a similar tool and check exactly what data is being sent over the network.

Comment: Sorry it's a typo.. In my edit you can see what is sent through the network. Is it enough for you?

Comment: The outgoing data looks good and matches your chrome test. I don't know WCF, but how are you instructing it to convert the incoming object (dictionary) into a `Foobar` instance?

Comment: I don't, it's done automatically. I will do a test with another REST client